# dnsmasq with unplugged ethernet port

Tags: networking, ethernet, dnsmasq

How do I get dnsmasq to bind to an ethernet port that is not plugged in?

The environment is such that the server is working in the capacity of a router. A workstation will be plugged into this ethernet port. Once plugged in the workstation will receive an address via DHCP and be routed to other network connections on the same server.

The situation is that there is no connection to the ethernet port at the time the server is started. This is a requirement. There can be no switch or other device in this path. (The port will also be used with hostapd in order to use 802.1X authentication.)

My testing shows that dnsmasq fails to start because the ethernet port is not available. If I plug in a device into the port and then reload dnsmasq, dnsmasq will connect to the port.

The great part is that when the port is unplugged, dnsmasq is fine! dnsmasq stays attached to the port. Plugging back into the port will provide DHCP services to the port!

How do I get dnsmasq to bind to the port after booting with nothing plugged into the port?

I'm expecting two possible directions (or surprise me with an alternative!)

1. Convince dnsmasq to bind to a port that is unplugged
2. Convince the network stack to show that a port is available even though it is unplugged

I'm using netplan to manage the network interfaces (ala Ubuntu 18).

The netplan configuration for the port is:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.1/24]
```

dnsmasq.conf looks like:

```
bogus-priv
no-resolv
server=1.1.1.1
interface=enp2s0
bind-interfaces
expand-hosts
dhcp-range=192.168.0.100,192.168.0.250,12h
```

---

Add the error message from dnsmsg

```
Nov 20 22:00:34 nuvo7006-2 dnsmasq[945]: dnsmasq: unknown interface enp2s0
Nov 20 22:00:34 nuvo7006-2 dnsmasq[945]: unknown interface enp2s0
Nov 20 22:00:34 nuvo7006-2 dnsmasq[945]: FAILED to start up
Nov 20 22:00:34 nuvo7006-2 systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=2
Nov 20 22:00:34 nuvo7006-2 systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 20 22:00:34 nuvo7006-2 systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
-- Subject: Unit dnsmasq.service has failed
```

Comment: Could you add the error from dnsmasq when it fails to start? Not just the line with the error, leave a bit of context around if that's possible.

Comment: 3. Convince dnsmasq to restart when the cable is plugged in (e.g. with https://linux.die.net/man/8/ifplugd)

Comment: Eduardo Trápani -- I added the error message from journalctl -xe. This message occurs on startup. The same message occurs if I restart dnsmasq.